# How to resolve the native image generator failed error in windows 8 store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps

While certifying the windows 8 app using WACK Kit, the native image generator failed error occurs. I don know how to resolve it, can any one say the procedure to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you all tried?  This should help people narrow down your problem and come up with a quick accurate answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [known issues in automatically generating native images](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716152) from Microsoft Support. It also includes a workaround if the troubleshooting steps don't work.